# Is there a way to write a correct-form json info to a .json file and read from it locally?

Tags: python, json, database

I am planning to use JSON file as a simple database, i am trying to append to it new entries and try to take my entries later.

This is the code i have:

```
import json
import time

try:
    with open('json_database.json', 'r') as json_database:
        profiles = json.load(json_database)
except FileNotFoundError:
    profiles = []
while True:
    answer = input('list info (l), write info (w), new info (a)').lower()

    if answer == 'w':
        break
    elif answer == 'l':
        print(profiles)
    else:
        username = input('username: ')
        email = input('Email: ')
        rating = input('Rating: ')
        lichess_profiles.append({
        'profile':{
        'username': lichess_username,
        'email': email,
        'rating': rating
        }
        })
with open('json_database.json', 'w') as json_database:
    json.dump(profiles, json_database)
```

Now i want to call the info from the JSON info ! thats what i added :

```
with open('json_database.json') as json_1:
    result = json.load(json_1)
print(result['profile']['email'])
```

what is the reason of that ? what shall i add ?

i tried that code but it raise this error :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What is result and where are you printing it? Also I am assuming "lichess_profiles" is the same as profiles, if not "lichess_profiles" is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: yeah but its the same, i just wanted to delete all lichess so the question will be general

i am printing the info to ```json_database.json```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base item you are writing to the json file is a list, but you're treating it like a dictionary. It *contains* dictionaries, but you have to access it like a list:

```
print(result[0]['profile']['email'])
print(result[1]['profile']['email'])
# etc.
```

Comment: what does ```[0]``` mean ??

Comment: It means "first item in the list".  `[1]` means "second item in the list", etc.